# Visualizing embeddings on Tensorboard using the output of a preloaded network

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was wondering how to visualize the embeddings that are from a preloaded network in Tensorboard. I'm using [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) to create the embeddings for faces, I have already created the `sprite.png` and `labels.tsv` files. As for loading the network and setting up for Tensorboard this is what I have done so far:

**1. Load the embedding layer**

```
meta_file, ckpt_file = facenet.get_model_filenames(MODEL_DIR)
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session().as_default() as sess:
        # load the network 
        model_dir_exp = os.path.expanduser(MODEL_DIR)
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_dir_exp, meta_file))
        saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), os.path.join(model_dir_exp, ckpt_file))

        # setup the lambda function needed to get the embeddings
        images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
        embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
        phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
        find_embeddings = lambda img : sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict = {images_placeholder : img, phase_train_placeholder : False})
```

**2. Find the embeddings**

```
face_embeddings = np.zeros((n_images,128))
face_embeddings = []
for i in range(n_batches):
    start = i * batch_size
    end = min((i + 1) * batch_size, n_images)

    # Get the embeddings
    face_embeddings[start:end, :] = find_embeddings(face_images[start:end])
```

**3. Setup Tensorboard**

```
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([33, 128]), name = "embedding")
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding_config = config.embeddings.add()
embedding_config.tensor_name = embedding.name
embedding_config.metadata_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'labels.tsv')
embedding_config.sprite.image_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR,'sprite.png')
embedding_config.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([160, 160])

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(MODEL_DIR)
projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)
```

Although when I load this in Tensorboard it says that it can't find the data. I've looked at the [FAQ](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md#my-tensorboard-isnt-showing-any-data-whats-wrong) and when I run `find MODEL_DIR | grep tfevents` nothing shows up so I'm guessing that this is the problem. I've looked at the [MNIST Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=885s) and it seems that they have checkpoints during the training step although I don't have it as I'm using a pre-trained model. Any ideas as how I would make Tensorboard show the embeddings in this case?

Comment: You'll need to use `tf.Saver()` to create a checkpoint. See the NMT seq2seq tutorial for some example code, or check the documentation.